# How should web.config be deployed?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, web-config

I am designing a web app that will be licensed to organisations to install on their Intranets. I am using the 'Publish' feature in VS 2010. This creates all the necessary aspx pages but compiles code into a DLL so it is not exposed to the client.

However, the published `web.config` remains editable so presumably the client could turn `<compilation debug="true">` to look at my code, or change the assembly references to effectively 'mod' the app. Is it necessary/possible to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're shipping source code, turning `<compilation debug="true">` will have no effect on the released/published DLLs.

You can obfuscate your DLLs so that even if they look it up in Reflector, it doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt the web.config file.

More details : [Walkthrough: Encrypting Configuration Information Using Protected Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky.aspx)

Comment: His concern was about editable web.config file. Unless you do Obfuscation you can't avoid people seeing your code.

Comment: No, his concern is with the customer reading his code. He _thinks_ that an editable `web.config` is the issue, though it isn't. Read the question carefully.

Comment: I agree. even if you Obfuscate .net code, it can viewed by Reflector, ideally there is no way to avoid this; Correct me if I am wrong; Obfuscation protects upto a certain level.

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply compiling your web app, anyone can decompile the code using a tool like Reflector.

`web.config` settings have no effect on this.

You may want to look at obfuscating your assemblies - [DotFuscator](http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator) is one obfuscation tool that is widely used, though there are [many others](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=obfuscating%20your%20assemblies#hl=en&pq=obfuscating%20your%20assemblies&xhr=t&q=.net%20obfuscator&cp=7&pf=p&sclient=psy&source=hp&aq=0&aqi=g5&aql=&oq=.net%20ob&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=7196a0a375ca027d&biw=1280&bih=939).